# APIError(code=-1099): Not found, unauthenticated, or unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, binance

I hope that you are having a good day.

I am working with the Binance api trough the [Python-Binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
My bot runs fine most of the time but for some reason after a while it randomly stops and gives me this error message. "APIError(code=-1099): Not found, unauthenticated, or unauthorized".
The error seems to happen at the same line of code everytime.

```
from binance.client import Client
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd 

class LastPrice():
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.api_key = "my key"
        self.secret_key = "my secret"


    def get_client(self):
        try:
            client = Client(self.api_key, self.secret_key)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        return client
    def get_last_price(self):
        last_price_string = self.get_client().get_ticker(symbol=self.symbol)['lastPrice']
        last_price = float(last_price_string)
        return last_price_string
    
    
    def get_last_price_and_time(self):
        last_price_string = self.get_client().get_ticker(symbol=self.symbol)['lastPrice']
        close_time = self.get_client().get_ticker(symbol=self.symbol)['closeTime']

        last_price = float(last_price_string)
        price_and_time = [close_time, last_price]

        return price_and_time
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcVzs.png)

I Have included a screenshot of my error message i get. Despite using the same code to generate the client everytime i only get the error in that specific code. My code stops because the client is referenced before assignement but I am looking for the cause of the precedent APIError.

Any idea what that error meassage means in the context of my code ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I also get this errors...